# How is erlang.cookie and rabbitmq related?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have accidentally deleted erlang.cookie and i cannot restart RabbitMQ server? What is the best way to make the server running again.

Comment: reboot of the server resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erlang cookie is a token needed by rabbitmq to use clustering. That's why he is required on server start.

Go to /var/lib/rabbitmq and check if .erlang.cookie is still here.
If not, try running

```
rabbitmqctl shutdown
rabbitmq-server
```

Considering the [erlang doc](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) this should regenerate your cookie.

> The first action of the Erlang network authentication server (auth) is then to read a file named $HOME/.erlang.cookie. If the file does not exist, it is created.

If this doesn't work, try to reboot the host, and if this still doesn't work can you post more details about the error message, and run

```
rabbitmqctl status
```

and show us what it gives you.

Comment: `rabbitmqctl shutdown` is unlikely to work - rabbitmqctl needs the cookie. It might be necessary to kill the processes with signals instead...

Comment: I tested this and it worked. I think that rabbitmq loads the cookie on start, which mean after that moment everything still woks even if you delete it. The shutdown will bring both rabbitmq AND erlang down, which mean the next restart will regenerate the cookie (cf my answer). rabbitmqctl start_app on the other hand, wouldn't work because the erlang vm wouldn't be restarted

Comment: I mean that rabbitmqctl reads the cookie when you start that to talk to Erlang to shutdown RabbitMQ, which does not seem to work. `Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie`

Comment: My quick check on a test VM: `rm /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie && rabbitmqctl shutdown` (`kill <beam.smp pid> <epmd pid>` works though)